# Typo3, set title for Mask Elements

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-mask

I have a typo3 server and using the mask extension. When an editor creates a new mask element, there isnt a title in the list view. Its always "no title":

[image]

I checked the database and found the titles in the db in the field: tt_content.header but no way to set them automatically oder manually by an editor. Anyone have an idea how the title can be set automatically? Oder manually by an editor?

Answer (score 1):

ext:`mask` has the option to reuse existing fields of `tt_content` for new kinds of content elements (CEs). use it to get the bonus of better interoperability with TYPO3.

TYPO3 has a logic how to show records (content elements) in the backend. one of it is the usage of the fields `header` and `description`. if you reuse these fields your CEs will look like others automatically.

If you use other fields you need to declare your fields for usage AND in case you change the kind of a CE from your kind to e.g. `TEXT with Media` the header stays.

Especially `header` is handled in the layout/partial of FSC or CSC global for any kind of CE. if the handling/rendering is changed (e.g. special layout) in an installation your CEs need special effort if they have their own building of the header.

Try to use the same fields as existing CEs and your life can be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, but I found a way around it for the meantime. I edit the mask element and chenge its type to something else—like Text—where I can set the title. After typing the title I save it, then change back to mask element and save again. This works by me without losing the content of the mask element. This way I can see the title in typo3 backend when I view as list or page or add content from another page. As I said, it doesn't solve the problem, but can help until there is a proper solution.

**EDIT**
I've just found another solution. You can add the title field to en existing mask element. To do it, go to ADMIN TOOLS > Mask, click your mask element to edit it. Add a new item by dragging the  item (the one on top of the list of available items) to the right where your items are. Then in General under   dropdown choose an  named:

: ()

Save, close, go to your page to add your title. This still doesn't add the title field automatically to all mask elements, but it is a step forward.

[image: Mask element backend title]

Answer (score 0):

If anywhere, you should be able to set a static title automatically in your page tsconfig. You could to something like

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.mask.elements.[title  of your mask element].tt_content_defValues {
    header = My Awesome title
}
```

Personally, I usually give every mask element a `header` field and ask content editors to fill it in.

See also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56964575/1876505) on Mask elements and backend titles.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Hey, first at all, thank you!
You have a little typo in your code. It should be mod.wizards, not wizWards.Waybe for other people better: 
But still, this dont work for me. I add this to my page.setup:
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.mask.elements.grid_item_big.tt_content_defValues {
    header = test
}
grid_item_big is the element-key of the mask element. Title is still "No title" in the list view. Even with the element title(Grid Item Bild) it doenst work but I think you dont mean the title.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing out the typo. I fixed it.

Are you sure this is the correct element key? In my installations, the CType of all Mask elements starts with `mask_`. Have you tried using `[...].mask_grid_item_big.[...]`?

What exactly do you mean by "Even with the element title [...] it doesn't work"? Do you mean it doesn't work if you give the element a header field?

Comment: Okay, maybe we are talking about different things. Im talking about a complete mask element that an admin can create in the backend. Do you talking about a content-element(from a mask element) created by an editor?
And yes, I tried it with tx_mask_grid_item_big. Doenst work